# Many to many not saving when updating/editing entity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I'm having a problem with my [HttpPost] edit method in my controller, it is not saving the changes made to a userrole, it is strange because the create method is working it is using the same helper methods, this is my code:

viewmodel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssignedUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel userViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = userViewModel.User;
            user.UserRoles.Clear();
            AddOrUpdateRoles(user, userViewModel.UserRoles);
            context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(userViewModel);
    }
```

Helper Method

```
private void AddOrUpdateRoles(User user, ICollection<AssignedUserRole> assignedUserRoles)
    {
        foreach (var assignedRole in assignedUserRoles)
        {
            if (assignedRole.Assigned)
            {
                var userRole = new UserRole { Id = assignedRole.UserRoleId };
                context.UserRoles.Attach(userRole);
                user.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
            }
        }
    }
```

everything in the User object is being updated except for the userrole, I can't find the problem as I am debugging and doing a step through and I can see that the user has the correct/updated roles assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by making the following changes:

```
 private void AddOrUpdateRoles(User user, ICollection<AssignedUserRole> assignedUserRoles)
    {
        foreach (var assignedRole in assignedUserRoles)
        {
            if (assignedRole.Assigned)
            {
                var userRole = context.UserRoles.Find(assignedRole.UserRoleId);
                user.UserRoles.Add(userRole);
            }
        }
    }


 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel userViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = userViewModel.User;
            context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.UserRoles).Load();
            user.UserRoles.Clear();
            AddOrUpdateRoles(user, userViewModel.UserRoles);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(userViewModel);
    }
```

I had to "Load" the user's userroles otherwise the clearing was doing nothing.